# Bootstrap works on localhost but not on Github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, github-pages

I am creating a portfolio website using Bootstrap 4, animate.css, typed.js and custom css.

Everything works fine when using localhost in VS Code but when viewing it in Github pages all styles and JS do not work. I am sure my links in head tag are correct but other opinions would be great! Please see code below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,400,700,900|Titillium:100,200,400,700,900+Web&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="/js/typed.js"></script>
    <title>Ryan Mottram Online Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- NAV BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top animated slideInDown">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="me.html">Ryan Mottram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Projects
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects.html">View All</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="wally-project.html">Where's Wally?</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="haskell-te-project.html">Haskell Text Editor</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="gtb-project.html">Going to Boston</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="pathfinder-project.html">Path Finder</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="webauth-project.html">Web Authoring Assessment</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="cipher-project.html">Caesar Cipher</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="algorithms-project.html">Searching and Sorting Algorithms</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="shufflegame-project.html">Shuffle Game</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="compsci-project.html">Computer Science Project</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
<!-- NAV BAR END -->

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid animated">
        <div id="container">
            <h2 class="typing-anim"><span class="type"></span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <!-- <div id="particles-js"> -->
            <div class="card">
                    <img src="/assets/me_hs.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-fluid animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="card-body"> <br>
                        <h1 class="animated slideInLeft">Who Am I?</h1> <br>
                        <p class="card-text animated slideInRight">An undergraduate originally from Lowestoft attending the University of Lincoln, UK studying
                            Computer Science. Giving you an insight to what I have done/doing/can do and would like to do for myself or even you?
                            <br> <br> So what you waiting for? Take a look at what I have done or read more about me and make your own opinion.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <!-- </div> -->

    <script src="/js/particles.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the link of the github pages repository?

Comment: https://rmottram.github.io/Portfolio/index.html

Comment: The problem is that use absolute path /css/style.css it will try to search for style.css inside https://rmottram.github.io/ not in protfolio, you need to use path "/portfolio/css/style.css" or "./css/style.css"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a problem with your paths.

So this is what GitHub is trying to get:

```
https://rmottram.github.io/js/script.js
```

What you want is probably:

```
https://rmottram.github.io/Portfolio/js/script.js
```

So I would suggest changing your paths from

```
/js/typed.js
```

to

```
./js/typed.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for your input, I turned out I needed to place './' before the path as Damien suggested, again thank you both!